# Create Workflow programmatically

Tags: 2013, workflow, custom

I'm about to create a custom workflow editor application for creating, configuring and publishing basic SharePoint 2013 List workflows.
I've found [this](http://sharepointdragons.com/2014/01/07/creating-and-managing-workflows/)

> A new and interesting feature of the Workflow Services Manager is that
>   it allows 3rd party vendors to create separate workflow designers that
>   leverage it and build a new UI to create workflows, and offer such
>   separate workflow designers to the audience in the form of SharePoint
>   Apps.

But haven't found any good article about the usage.

What would be the best approach to achieve the goal?

Comment: Check out this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/607127/Using-SharePoint-Workflow-Services-JS-API